# Как сделать несколько запросов через requests без обновления страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Я пытаюсь написать программку на Python версии 3.9 для вытягивания данных из html кода страницы, чтобы дальше вставить их в нужное мне поле в этой же странице. Сначала я обращаюсь к странице, чтобы взять код через `requests.get`, делаю нужную операцию, находя значение `value`, но когда я снова обращаюсь к сайту через `requests.post`, чтобы вставить это значение в нужное поле, у меня открывается уже другая сессия и соответственно значение `value` уже другое, не то, которое было до этого. Как мне действовать в рамках одной сессии, чтобы после проделанных действий я вставил своё значение `value` в ту сессию, которая и была открыта изначально? Всё работает исправно, кроме этого момента с обновлением сессии. Спасибо!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://idil24.space/login")
print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")


def auto():
    if soup.find(id="One") and soup.find_all(class_="form-control col-2 mr-2"):
        c = soup.find(id='One_hidden')
        return c['value']
    elif soup.find(id="Two") and soup.find_all(class_="form-control col-2 mr-3"):
        c = soup.find(id='Two_hidden')
        return c['value']
    elif soup.find(id="Answer") and soup.find_all(class_="form-control col-2 mr-2"):
        c = soup.find(id='Answer_hidden')
        return c['value']


j = requests.post("http://idil24.space/login", data={'One': auto(),
                                                     'Two:': auto(),
                                                     'Answer': auto()})

    print(j.text)
```

Comment: Для ваших целей нужно выполнять код в рамках одной сессии. Почитать о сессиях можно [тут](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/)

Comment: я уже изучал эту статью, вот попробовал сделать в рамках одной сессии, но все равно не выходит

https://pastebin.com/ayej6XUG

Comment: одними сессиями там не обойтись, разный формат капчи: 5+6=Х, 10+X=12, Х*2=20... нужно проработать и отправить в post параметрами one, two, symbol, answer UPD сек, они там есть в htlm, нужно только распарсить UPD како-то hash еще есть...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, requests.Session() действительно нужен (вернее, с ним удобнее), т.к. сайт устанавливает кукиз и позже проверяет их, поэтому

```py
url = 'http://idil24.space/login'
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Referer': 'http://idil24.space/login'
        }

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

и тут обнаруживается, что все составляющие для капчи есть в коде... внезапно:

```py
one = soup.find('input', id='One_hidden')['value']
two = soup.find('input', id='Two_hidden')['value']
symbol = soup.find('input', id='Symbol_hidden')['value']
answer = soup.find('input', id='Answer_hidden')['value']
hash_value = soup.find('input', id='hash_hidden')['value']
type_value = soup.find('input', id='Type_hidden')['value']

print(f'one: {one}, two: {two}, symbol: {symbol}, answer: {answer}')
print(f'type: {type_value}, hash: {hash_value}')
```

выведет что-то наподобие:

```
one: 8, two: 6, symbol: 2, answer: 2
type: 1, hash: jktTCDIFK2m1l9MbGc4QvGMTAqk1L8dWiXGDGp5rJWoAFESMuKN9R085CljSvlM0
```

hash тоже запрашивается в качестве параметра, поэтому забирайте и его, а дальше сделайте запрос на тот же адрес, но уже post, и передайте:

```
payload = {
        'login': login,
        'password': password,

        'one': one,
        'two': two,
        'symbol': symbol,
        'answer': answer,

        'type': type_value,
        'hash': hash_value,
    }
```

Все вместе:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def login(login, password):
    url = 'http://idil24.space/login'
    headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Referer': 'http://idil24.space/login'
        }

    session = requests.Session()

    r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    one = soup.find('input', id='One_hidden')['value']
    two = soup.find('input', id='Two_hidden')['value']
    symbol = soup.find('input', id='Symbol_hidden')['value']
    answer = soup.find('input', id='Answer_hidden')['value']
    hash_value = soup.find('input', id='hash_hidden')['value']
    type_value = soup.find('input', id='Type_hidden')['value']

    print(f'one: {one}, two: {two}, symbol: {symbol}, answer: {answer}')
    print(f'type: {type_value}, hash: {hash_value}')

    payload = {
        'login': login,
        'password': password,

        'one': one,
        'two': two,
        'symbol': symbol,
        'answer': answer,

        'type': type_value,
        'hash': hash_value,
    }

    r = session.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    print(r)
    print(r.text)
```

PS у меня выполнение `login('admin', 'qwerty')`, ожидаемо, возвращает

```
<Response [200]>
Не верный пароль.
```

но у вас-то есть доступ к сайту? ;)

PPS Удачного парсинга!

Comment: большое спасибо! вы очень помогли!